# how to use list object in a object in wcf

Tags: .net, wcf

I have wcf Service, i have mentioned below three class in which i used the first two class to get the object from the client side.. On **StudentsInformation** class i have to pass a list ie which contains a list of subects there name , mark, avg etc.. which i tried to pass as list..I want to make a database updation according to the number of subjects, and how to check this in WebcLient... (ie how to pass data in list) Can you help me..with this

```
 [DataContract(Name = "StudentsInformation")]
    public class StudentsInformation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Total { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Subjects> Subjectslist { get; set; }
    }



 [DataContract(Name = "Subjects")]
    public class Subjects
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string SubjName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Mark { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Avg { get; set; }
    }


[DataContract(Name = "ReturnList")]
public class ReturnList
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TotalMark { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int StudenID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

And in the svc cs i have

```
 public List<ReturnList> GetStudentdetails(StudentsInformation objStudentsInfo)
        {
            string StudentName = objStudentsInfo.Name;
            int StudentID = objStudentsInfo.ID;
            List<ReturnList> data = new List<ReturnList>();
            //loop with objStudentsInfo.Subjectslist and calls DB
            return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly valid in WCF services to use a List<> in a return value or parameter, but you may be using a client-side proxy incorrectly ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592085/calling-client-side-wcf-service-with-type-listof-t))